# Why direct column value comparison is not evaluating after multiple like clause in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a search query like following:

```
SELECT p.product_id, p.product_title,p.product_long_description 
  FROM products p   
  WHERE p.product_title            LIKE '%t-shirt01%' 
    OR  p.product_long_description LIKE '%t-shirt01%' 
   AND  p.product_status='active'
```

In this case the last p.product_status='active' is not evaluating. Can anybody explain the logical reason for not evaluating the last comparison.

Answer (score 1):

You should use brackets around the OR condition:

```
SELECT p.product_id, p.product_title,p.product_long_description 
  FROM products p   
  WHERE (p.product_title            LIKE '%t-shirt01%' 
       OR  p.product_long_description LIKE '%t-shirt01%')
       AND  p.product_status='active'
```

Your current solution will filter the non-active products that match the solution (title). And the active ones which has the t-shirt01 in the description.

The SQL parser works like those cheap chinese calculators, it starts with the first one:

Does the title contains t-shirt? YES -> Lets show this row.

NO -> Does the description contains t-shirt? YES -> Is it active? -> YES -> Lets show this row.
  If it doesn't contains the t-shirt in the description and/or inactive it won't show the row.

However by adding brackets () yo can change the evaluation. Just like in math with the * +. In boolean the AND/OR is equivalent.

Comment: Your solution is correct. Can you explain the reason. Basically i want to know working procedure behind the scene.

Comment: added some more explanation

Answer (score 0):

And/or behaves the Same as * and +
You need to add ( ) somewhere

Maybe like this `( ... OR ... ) AND .....`.